# RPM Dependencies Troubleshooting

Tags: apache-httpd, nagios

I am trying to install a Nagios rpm and I get the following error

```
error: Failed dependencies:
        httpd is needed by nagios-4.0.2-2.el6.x86_64
        php is needed by nagios-4.0.2-2.el6.x86_64
```

I am also pretty novice with linux but I assume httpd is already running because when I run `service httpd status` is already running.

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Reading around](http://www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-yum-and-vs-rpm/) it seems that

- > RPM package manager is unable to track dependencies
- > YUM adds automatic updates and dependency management

for this I would prefer to use `yum` whenever is possible. I don't know exactly the problem in your case, but I would try to fix it using one of the following two approaches :

#### Install rpm and resolve dependencies with yum

lets say, you really want to install nagios via rpm because you want very last version, you could try to remove the current versions of `php` and `httpd` (backup httpd conf and sites in case) and reinstall everything together with one command

```
yum localinstall /path/to/nagios.rpm
```

it will install rpm and resolve dependencies automatically.

#### Enable a repository and avoid rpm

But maybe the very last version is not necessary, then you could [enable `EPEL Repository`](http://www.tecmint.com/how-to-enable-epel-repository-for-rhel-centos-6-5/) and install all the needed packages from there and from your other repos. Give a look at [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nagios-on-centos-6)

Comment: how do I get more detailed log ? the funniest thing is both httpd and php are already installed. Do I need different version of those ?

Answer (score 0):

The message indicates that as far as RPM is concerned, neither httpd nor php are installed. It doesn't cite versions, so it just requires *some* package that offers those functionalities. You say at least httpd is running, so RPM doesn't know about that.

This looks like you installed packages directly from source (or dropped the contents of a tarball into the system, or installed packages that aren't built for CentOS). If so, I'd suggest you back up your data, and do a *clean* install from CentOS + EPEL, and restore the relevant data from backup. Getting the system all messed up (dependency-wise) is easy, and next to impossible to fix.